# What is meant by intraplate volcanism?

Tags: rocks, petrology, igneous, volcanic-eruption, ocean-ridge

I am having massive confusion on whether **intraplate volcanism** refers to volcanism occurring at **plate boundaries** or away from **plate boundaries** (such as formation of **[ocean island basalts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_island_basalt)**), or perhaps both?

Also, are **[mid-oceanic ridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_island_basalt)** related to **intraplate volcanism**?

Comment: Faraz, I tried to clean up your question a tad to make it easier for people to understand your confusion, and add some links, but a good question, and certainly feel free to make sure it still embodies what you were asking!

Comment: Nice , thanks a ton for the edit! Yep, it still asks what I wanted it to ask, in a more concise manner though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The majority of Earth's volcanoes occur in plate boundaries. These can be at spreading ridges (green dots on the map) where they are mostly underwater, but sometimes are above the water (such as in Iceland). They can also be on convergent margins, for example the Pacific ring of fire.

A less common type of volcano is the intraplate volcano, which are basically all volcanoes not in plate margins because that are inside (="intra") a plate. Hawaii is probably the most famous example, together with the abundant seamounts elsewhere in the Pacific. They are usually formed by deeper processes, with mantle plumes coming from below the lithosphere.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Terms**:
Intraplate volcanism - as the name suggests it is volcanism within the plates rather than at plate boundaries.

These are also known as [hotspots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_(geology)).

Ocean island basalt (OIB) - is the basaltic rocks associated with intraplate volcanism.

**Relation between mid-ocean ridges and hotspots**:

Hotspot–ridge interaction produces a wide range of phenomena including excess crustal thickness, geochemical anomalies, off-axis
volcanic ridges, and ridge relocations or jumps.

For further study refer to this [research paper](https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/GG/FACULTY/ITO/Reprints/Mittelstaedt_etal_EPLS08.pdf).

A conceptual schematic of a ridge jump from that paper:

[image: https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/GG/FACULTY/ITO/Reprints/Mittelstaedt_etal_EPLS08.pdf]

[image: http://www.nongnu.org/magellan/magellan_ridgejump.html]

[Image Source](http://www.nongnu.org/magellan/magellan_ridgejump.html)

DR: Dying rift
PR: Propagating rift

There is a ridge jump towards the hotspot.  Due to the ridge jump lithosphere from plate B is transfered to plate A.

Comment: Good answer, I attempted a few minor tweaks, though don't know the subject as well as you do, so certainly make sure I didn't mess anything up.  Do you have a source for the final image?

Answer (score 2):

[Intra = within/on the inside](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intra), so intraplate volcanism would be volcanism happening far from plate boundaries, usually hotspots.

If you have trouble remembering intra- vs inter- remember international trade = trade from one nation to others, domestic trade would be intra-national trade even though no one uses that term.